# Event doesn't update on mousedown when using .bind() with function arguments

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, prototype, bind

I'am trying to rewrite a jQuery plugin without jQuery and I can't quite figure out why the event won't update in a function when I'm using `.bind()` with arguments. I have simplified the problem to the following:

```js
function IMdraw(div) {
    this.div = div
    this.div.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedown.bind(this));
}

IMdraw.prototype = {

    onMouseMove: function (fn) {
        this.moveHandler = fn;
        this.div.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler, false);
    },
    
    move1: function(e, arg) {
        console.log('move1')
        console.log(e.offsetX);
        console.log(e.offsetY);
    },

    move2: function(e) {
      console.log('move2')
      console.log(e.offsetX);
      console.log(e.offsetY);
    },


    mousedown: function(e) {
      var arg = 3;
      this.onMouseMove(this.move1.bind(this));
      this.onMouseMove(this.move2.bind(this, e, arg));

    },

}

var obj = new IMdraw(document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; height:500px; background: blue;">
  </div>
```

As you can see when clicking in the blue div and move the cursor around in the div, in `move2` function, the `offsetX` and `offsetY` does not update but it does in the `move1` function.

Is there an explanation why it behaves this way? I believe I'am using the `.bind()` incorrectly.

Comment: remove that e and arg arguments and make your arg as this.arg

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the best solution in the plugin, I would rather want to pass it then have it as a global variable in the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `bind` calls are interfering with the automatic passing of event objects to event callback functions.

- With `move1`, you aren't passing anything, so `e` correctly points to
  the `mousemove` event that is automatically passed to the event
  callback function. `arg` was not passed, so `arg` (inside `move1`) would be `undefined`.
- With `move2`, you are interfering with the automatic passing of the event object by passing arguments of your own. The `e` argument you are
  passing is the event object from the `mousedown` event, which doesn't
  get updated when `mousemove` happens, so you always see the offsets from when the mouse was clicked. You did pass `arg` to `move2` and that would have been available.

The solution is to not pass the event object at all and let that be automatically passed as it normally is and to only pass any extra data you need (`arg` in your case), **BUT the argument(s) you pass will be the first ones received by the function in this case and the event will be the LAST (opposite of what normally happens).**

FROM **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**:

> **Syntax**: *`fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`*
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ***thisArg***
>
> The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target function
>   when the bound function is called. The value is ignored if the bound
>   function is constructed using the new operator.
>
> ***arg1, arg2, ...***
>
> Arguments to ***prepend*** to arguments provided to the bound function
>   when invoking the target function.

Here's a working solution. I've made some minor adjustments so that you are using `addEventListener` instead of `onmousemove`, which is more modern and standards-based.

```js
function IMdraw(div) {
 this.div = div;
 this.div.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedown.bind(this));
}

IMdraw.prototype = {
 onMouseMove: function (fn) {
  this.div.addEventListener('mousemove', fn);
 },
 
 move1: function(arg, e) {
  console.log('move1');
   console.log(e.offsetX, "Passed argument: " + arg);
    console.log(e.offsetY, "Passed argument: " + arg);
 },

 move2: function(arg, e) {
    console.log('move2');
   console.log(e.offsetX, "Passed argument: " + arg);
    console.log(e.offsetY, "Passed argument: " + arg);
 },

 mousedown: function(e) {
     console.log(this.div);
     var arg = 3;
     // The e argument represents the mousedown event that was fired. It only happens
     // once, when you click the mouse. It won't happen again when you move the mouse
     // so the values associated with it don't change on move1 and move2.
     // Instead, don't pass the event object at all (let that happen organically as it
     // normally does) and pass just the extra data you want to pass. This extra argument
     // will be the FIRST argument recieved by the bound function and the event will be
     // the SECOND.
     this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", this.move1.bind(this, arg));
     this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", this.move2.bind(this, arg));
 }
}

var obj = new IMdraw(document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; height:500px; background: blue;">
  </div>
```

Comment: But the arg variable is not passed to the move2 function. I would rather want to pass the arg variable then have it as a global variable in the prototype.

Comment: @user4282812 I've updated the answer to fully explain the issue and the solution that allows you to do what you are trying to do.